# How to calculate age from birth date using SQL in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

So I'm trying to create scope for **User** model. It goes like this:

```
scope :select_by_age_range, lambda { |age_range|
                                includes(:profile).where("(date_part('year', now()) - date_part('year', profile.birth_date)) >= ? AND (date_part('year', now()) - date_part('year', profile.birth_date)) <= ?", age_range.first, age_range.last)
                              }
```

I want to select all users in given **age_range**, but it gives me an error:

**ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "profile" (PG::UndefinedTable)**

I tried to add **SELECT birth_date FROM profile**, but it gives me syntax error.

I also tried to add **.references(:profiles)** at the end of query, but it doesn't help either.

Any suggestions?

Ps. I am not familiar with SQL. What you see here is: "I have no idea what I'm doing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is likely named `profiles` in the database. Therefore, you have to use `profiles.birth_date` in the query instead of `profile.birth_date`.

Btw. I would simplify the query to:

```
scope :select_by_age_range, lambda { |age_range|
  includes(:profile)
    .where(profiles: { birth_date: (age_range.begin.years.ago..age_range.end.years.ago) })
}
```

Comment: That's it, thank you very much :) Two things only:
 where(profile:... It has to be 'profile'
I had to reverse range. The end is first, the beginning is last. Otherwise it creates a range like (21..0)